# Error with with installing PyCuda, cannot find -lboost_thread-gcc42-mt

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I am trying to get some software called pycuda  (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycuda) installed on ubuntu. The error I am receiving is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_python-gcc42-mt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread-gcc42-mt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'c++' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

I have installed Boost and a few other packages with the word boost in that looked appropriate and yet I still get the same error message. Would anybody know where I can find and install these files?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to search for any other files to install PyCUDA. PyCUDA's dependencies will be resolved automatically if you open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python-pycuda
```

python-pycuda is a Python module to access Nvidia‘s CUDA parallel computation API. PyCUDA lets you access Nvidia‘s CUDA parallel computation API from Python.

Comment: Excellent. This seems to have worked. Thanks